# How to add a line item to a related list from a custom button?

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, related-list, urlhacking, quote

I have created a custom list button using the wizard on a related list. The button is to add a line item to the list from the Products list. The problem is that the URL being used in the custom button goes to the specified products page but when i try to add the product it only adds to the standard quote line item list and not to the related list. I have taken the URL from the Quote Line Items -> Add line item Button.

This is the URL being used: https://na9.salesforce.com/_ui/sales/quote/SelectSearch?addTo={!Quote.Id}&retURL={!Quote.Id}

Here are the screenshots:
The highlighted area is the custom button for the related list bid alternates. When i try to add to this list from the button it adds to the list Quote line items above it. 
[image]

This is the page that the custom button points to, basically adds the product and it's price into the related list.
[image]

Is there a specific id to be used so that the line item is added to the related list?? Any help would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: screen shots would be helpful -- it is hard to understand your issue

Comment: i have added the screenshots,i hope it is clear now. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: so you are url hacking to display the `add quote line items to` page but want the resulting line items to be added to the `Bid Alternatives` related list?

Comment: Yes! That's right.

Comment: This will never work, the URL creates `Quote Line Items` which are always children of `Quote`

Comment: Is there any other way than URL hacking to add to the related list through a custom button?

Comment: certainly - a custom button that invokes a VF page/controller.  You'll have to rebuild the product select functionality  (or at least as much as you need)